# How i can use .replace(Fragment , mapsFragment)? Android

Tags: java, google-maps, android-fragments

I have use .replace() for replace a old Fragment with a new, but in this moment i do no how use the same of .replace() by a Fragment to a mapsFragment.

Ideas?!
I can use replace? if i can' t use it, what I can use?

This is my code in this moment. (the .replace() don' t work)

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    mapsFragment fragM = null;
    Fragment frag = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0: //Home
            mTitle = "Maps";
            fragM = new mapsFragment();
            break;

        case 1: //Query utente
            mTitle = "Section 2";
            break;

        case 2: //Query Amministratore
            mTitle = "Section 3";
            break;
    }

    if (position != 3) {
        if(position==0){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragM)
                    .commit();
        }else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, frag)
                    .commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution:[link where i have found it](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.it/2013/03/google-maps-android-api-v2-mapfragment.html)

This is the code in particular:

```
if(position==0){
            FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            SupportMapFragment mFRaFragment = new mapsFragment();
            mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFRaFragment);
            mTransaction.commit();
        }else {
```